# The logical comparison inside the loop crashes when it encounters zero

Tags: r, loops, logical-operators

I wanted to explain my problem with codes

```
example_1 <- sample(-100:100, 100)    # simple sample for my question
example_1[30] <- NA                   # changed one of them to NA
not_equal_zero <- matrix(NA, 100, 1)  # matrix to find out if there is any zeros (1 for TRUE, 0 for FALSE)

for (i in 1:100) {                    # check each observation if it is 0 assign 1 to "not equal zero matrix"
  if (example_1[i] == 0) {
    not_equal_zero[i] <- 1
  } else {
    not_equal_zero[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

When i = 30 it finds 0, and terminates. I am not checking only against zero. I have special values. What is the solution for this problem?

```
2 == 0    # it gives FALSE
0 == 0    # it gives TRUE
NA == 0   # it gives NA but i need FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

`NA` gives `NA` when compared to *anything*. You probably want to replace:

```
if (example_1[i] == 0)
```

with:

```
if (!is.na(example_1[i]) && example_1[i] == 0)
```